# Running a Rails controller method from shell?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unix

In a controller for a rails project I have, there is a helper function that sends an e-mail containing all the changes to the database done in the past week. I also have a cron job on Unix that runs a number of bash scripts every weekend related to my web application. Is there an easy method to run a controller's helper function from a standalone .rb file or bash script?

Comment: My first instinct would be to move the helper function to its own class, perhaps in `lib`.

Answer (score 2):

If you're actually wanting to make the web request from within your crontab, you can just call `wget` or `curl` on the target URL.

```
0 * * * * wget http://yourdomain.com/path/to/request -o /dev/null
```

If you're wanting to execute this mailer outside the context of a web request, this sort of behavior should not be in your controller. This is what `lib/` is for.

You can create a file like `lib/my_helpers.rb` containing

```
module MyHelpers
  extend self

  def your_mailer(some, params, here)
    # runthe mailer
  end
end
```

You can include this in whatever controller you want, or even `ApplicationController`

```
include ::MyHelpers
```

Wherever it is included, you can then simply call `your_mailer(param1, param2, param3)` to execute it.

You would then include this from within a rake task, and execute the rake task from your crontab. Create a file in `lib/tasks/your_mailer.rake` with something like this

```
include MyHelpers

namespace :myapp do
  desc "Runs your_mailer"
    task :mailer => :environment do
    your_mailer(param1, param2, param3)
  end
end
```

Comment: I'm getting an `uninitialized constant MailerHelper` when I try to run this. It's great help so far, though!

Comment: Make sure `config/application.rb` has `config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib"]`

Comment: Still getting the problem.

In /lib/mailer_helper.rb
`module MailerHelper
  extend self

  def summaryemail
    @date = DateTime.now.beginning_of_week.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
    SummaryMailer.weekly_email(@date).deliver
  end
end`

In /lib/tasks/mailer_helper.rake
`include MailerHelper

namespace :status do
  desc "Runs Mailer"
    task :mailer => :environment do
    summaryemail
  end
end`